# ArcGIS Publish query layer as Feature Service fails

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, query-layer

I have a query layer that's simply a DB view call in PostgreSQL, the view is as such:

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW daily_query AS 
 SELECT b.id, b.first_name, b.last_name, 
    c.assignment_date::date AS assignment_date, d.case_id, d.case_sequence, 
    d.status, a.address_complete, a.the_geom_point
   FROM universe a, staff b, enumerator_assignments c, 
    enumerator_case_assignments d
  WHERE b.id = c.enumerator_id AND c.objectid = d.enumerator_assignments_id AND a.id = d.case_id;`

The query layer is simply a call to the view

`select * from daily_query`

The layer renders fine in ArcMap - but then I try to publish the layer as a Service to ArcGIS Server,  I want this to be a FeatureService so I enable "Feature Access" Capability and I only allow "Query" operation.  and I don't allow "Geometry Updates".

When I run "Analyze" it returns with "00134: Layer's data source is not supported"

The Service Analyzes and Publishes fine if I don't enable "Feature Access" on it.

I'm running 10.2.2

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have editing capabilities through that DB connection? I believe enabling Feature Access implies editing privileges.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that half the tables were SDE enabled and half were not (thus ArcGIS could not enable editing capability).

Turned out I did not need Feature access, and map service was more than enough.